# Enlarge a drawer opening

Tags: wood, kitchens

I need to know what tool and instructions or suggestions  on how to make my kitchen drawer openings taller. The drawer faces are tall enough to cover another 3/4 " and i really could use that little bit of height. There is a quartz counter top installed and so i wont be able to use a normal type of router on the top drawers. Thanks

Comment: Pictures would help.

Comment: I have photos but havent looked into how to attach them here. I will when i have a few minutes.

Answer (score 2):

Cabinet front faces are normally built as a structural frame. In general trying to cut away part of that frame can literally mean that the frame could fall apart as you cut into the doweling or mortise and tenon joints that hold the frame together. What you propose is not something I would recommend.

I think that you may be asking an X Y type question here. You should really step back and re-evaluate how much junk you are stuffing into your drawers that they are so full that they need another three quarters inch to be able to close. I see two things to consider instead:

1. Take a hard look at how much stuff is in those drawers that never gets used. If you are like most of us there is probably 30% or more content that can be taken out for donation, charity or throw away.
2. If your situation is one where kitchen drawer space is very poorly designed and minimal then take a look to see if there is some way to gain some more space. Some ideas that come to mind are to add a kitchen island with added cabinet space/drawers or to purge the dishwasher (pick up the old craft of hand washing dishes) and retrofit the dryer space with more drawers.

Comment: Normaly i would agree with u about losing extra  junk BUT in this case all the junk is gone. I hate clutter. Anyway these drawers are designed so even a small box of clingwrap wont fit if it isnt tucked in closed without snagging on the way back out. Its been a long standing gripe and Im just fed up. Was hopeing for a solution but i guess Im not goong to find one that doesnt involve more inconvience than the current problem gives me. Thanks anyway

Comment: I thought some about the structural issue and think if i just clear the space involved with doweling joints etc. and then cut that alone will make those top drawers more usable. So now, i jjust need tool blade advise. I am not a woodworker so am not familiar with what type of tool would work most efficiently to get this accomplished